# Entry and Exit prints in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, debugging, logging, linux-kernel

I want to know which all functions are executed in a particular scenario .

To be specific I want to understand MMC/SD card stack in **Linux kernel.**

My idea was to put prints like this :

```
pr_info("Entering %s\n", __func__);

pr_info("Leaving %s\n", __func__);
```

to all the functions present in `drivers/mmc/` .

But this is a tedious task.

Is there a better method to do this ?

Note :  I explored the possibility of using instrumentation functions provided  by gcc `__cyg_profile_func_enter` and `__cyg_profile_func_exit`.

Those instrumentation functions work perfectly for small modules.

But can these functions be used in Linux Kernel also ? Or do we have some different method for this?

My environment : The code will be cross compiled for Cortex A7/A9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile the source files you want with `-finstrument-functions`. Then you can implement these two functions yourself, in some file of the kernel.

Note that:

1. You must not compile the file containing `__cyg_profile_func_enter/exit` with `-finstrument-functions` (or, you should use `__attribute__((no_instrument_function))`).
2. The functions `__cyg_profile_func_enter/exit` must not call code compiled with `-finstrument-functions` - this will lead to infinite recursion. If all they do is `printk`, and `printk` and the low-level drivers it calls are not compiled this way, you're OK.

Comment: @LeoMessi, better now?

Comment: but where so I mention the -finstrument-functions in Makefile ?

Comment: I don't know Linux makefiles so well. I'd guess `CFLAGS += finstrument-functions` might do it. I'm sure SO contains answers about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try also the Linux `ftrace` tracer:

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt
- [A look at ftrace [LWN.net]](http://lwn.net/Articles/322666/)